# How to draw Any kind of Shape in React Native

Tags: react-native, layout, jsx, shapes

I m new to react-native. and I want to design the basketball court.
and every part of this layout will be clickable independently.

I m just tired of this.
Please help me out if anyone knows how to solve this.
every effort will be appreciated.

[image: here is the example image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw these kinds of shapes with SVG format with a design tool (like Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape etc.), then you can import your SVG to your react-native project using [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg) library. You can show SVG directly, or you can convert your SVG file as react-native-svg component with [SVGR Playground](https://react-svgr.com/playground/). I suggest you convert your SVG to a component if you want control over your SVG (for ability to change colors and sizes etc.).

Comment: bro I tried it. but SVG shapes are not fitting in the design like taking the same extra space somewhere or shapes are not the as same size as it's next shap size.
any clue?

Comment: and one more thing working with the svg components.